# Is it possible to use libcurl without file descriptor based socket?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, libcurl

I wrote the following libcurl code with my custom write and read socket functions:

```
//...
CURL *curl;
FILE *fp;
CURLcode res;
char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "file";
curl = curl_easy_init();

/* no progress meter please */
//curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &sharedValue);

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, read_data);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, &sharedValue);

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETFUNCTION, opensocket);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETDATA, &sharedValue);

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CLOSESOCKETFUNCTION, closecb);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CLOSESOCKETDATA, &sharedValue);

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, hostname.c_str());

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SOCKOPTFUNCTION, sockopt_callback);

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

I didn't know what to do with `CURLOPT_SOCKOPTFUNCTION` so I did `sockopt_callback` which is

```
static curl_socket_t opensocket(void *clientp,
                                curlsocktype purpose,
                                struct curl_sockaddr *address)
{
    return 0;
}
```

But I get

```
*   Trying 212.183.159.230:80...
* Could not set TCP_NODELAY: Socket operation on non-socket
* connect to 212.183.159.230 port 80 failed: Socket operation on non-socket
libcurl wants to close 0 now
```

because probably it's trying to write to the socket `0`. Apparently I can't prevent it from calling options on the socket, for example setting `TCP_NODELAY` and most important, `connect`.

Is it possible to make libcurl do not call the socket file descriptor ever?

One idea I had was to pass an existing socket to be a dummy for libcurl and then still use my write and read functions. However, libcurl simply send things through the socket, not the write and read functions

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do at all. Using curl, but not using sockets seems like a very weird use case.

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @domen instead of using kernel's TCP/IP stack I'm trying to use my own stack, that's why I don't need file descriptors at all

Comment: So you're trying to use http-over-your_own_stack? You might be out of luck if curl needs tcp sockets, but if it's not very fussy, maybe `socketpair` can work for you. You'd need to connect your stack to it though. What's the existing API for your stack?

Comment: @domen I started doing a `socketpair` right now but I realized it does not have a connect, and `libcurl` is calling connect and also setting a socket option on the file descriptor. Am I missing something? ps: what you think about passing a fake socket? I tried that but libcurl simply ignores my write and read functions and connects/downloads the index page through the socket...

Comment: @LucasZanella https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SOCKOPTFUNCTION.html says there is a value you can return to tell curl not to connect.

Comment: @user253751 nice, thanks. So, currently, I'm receiving google's HTML responde in the write_data function. This does not make sense, shouldn't I see the http request on write and http response on read? The way it's working now itś  that it's doing all the work in the socket file descriptor and passing the http response to write_data

Comment: @LucasZanellA CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION seems to be for writing the response to the file/screen. Did you read the documentation? https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html "This callback function gets called by libcurl as soon as there is data received that needs to be saved"

Comment: @domen thanks, `socketpair` worked for me! Really nice idea. After disabling connect it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I thought `write_data` was a way to redirect the socket calls but it has nothing to do with it, it actually is a function that writes what the client receives.

However, by passing a `socketpair`, as sugested by @domen, I made it work!

Sketch:

```
    //...

    static curl_socket_t opensocket(void *clientp,
                                curlsocktype purpose,
                                struct curl_sockaddr *address)
    {
        auto *sharedValue = static_cast<SharedValue *>(clientp);
        return sharedValue->curl_socket;
    }

    int socket_vector[2];
    if (0 != socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, socket_vector))
    {
        std::cout << "problem creating socketpair" << std::endl;
        std::exit(2);
    }

    sharedValue.curl_socket = socket_vector[0];
    sharedValue.vpn_socket = socket_vector[1];

    //writes the result to a file
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data_file);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, destFile);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETFUNCTION, opensocket);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETDATA, &sharedValue);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CLOSESOCKETFUNCTION, closecb);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CLOSESOCKETDATA, &sharedValue);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SOCKOPTFUNCTION, sockopt_callback);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, hostname.c_str());

    //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    
    //Start a thread here that will read/write to the socket pair on the other endpoint (in my case vpn_socket)

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    if (res)
    {
        std::cout << "libcurl error code: " << res << ", libcurl error: " << curl_easy_strerror(res) << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
```